# Stop saving data to primary key column

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, primary-key

I have a table, in which i have two columns: regular id(integer i mean) and uuid. in practice im using uuid for everything however there is one problem: the data i have in my db comes from outside INCLUDING the original integer ids.
My question is how can i stop saving to the integer id column?
Its not possible to make primary key accept blanks(?).
Its not possible to make primary key accept repeated values(?).
I cannot just delete the primary key column(?)

So bottom line i need to allow my table to save information without original integer primary key. is that possible somehow?
(im using postgres)

Comment: When you delete the primary key constraint, you can leave the column empty (NULL). But why can't you drop the column?

Comment: how do i do that exactly?

Comment: ALTER TABLE and do your stuff: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html